# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a 2D array of string and i am trying to pass the array into a table however i get the error

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17045d8b0'**

I have 3 tables and two of them depend on each other in order to populate a table. So say a user selects an item in table A, then table B should be populated based on table A's input. Table A contains categories and table B  contain subcategories of a category selected.

For category i have a one dimensional array and for subCategories i have a 2D array.

Table B 2D array picture :
[image]

My question is how do i access that 2D array such that when a user clicks a category in category table, i can pass that indexPath.row value to the next table which is the subcategory table with a 2D array. So that i get the relevant subCategories.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


if (tableView == _queryTypeTableView) {

    _contentArray = [_queryTypeCv mutableCopy];
}
else if (tableView == _categoriesTableView){

    _contentArray = [_categoryCv mutableCopy];
}
else if (tableView == _subCategoriesTableView){

        _contentArray = [_subcategoryCv mutableCopy];

}

return [self.contentArray count];

}
```

> 

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if ([tableView isEqual:_queryTypeTableView]) {

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.queryTypeCv objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
}
else if ([tableView isEqual:_categoriesTableView]){

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.categoryCv objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    _selectedCategoryIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
}

else if ([tableView isEqual:_subCategoriesTableView]){

        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.subcategoryCv objectAtIndex:_selectedSubCategoryIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
}
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if ([tableView isEqual:_queryTypeTableView]) {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_queryTypeTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_queryTypeButton setTitle:cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _queryTypeTableView.hidden = YES;
    _categoriesButton.enabled = YES;
    _categoriesButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    NSLog(@"You selected 1------> %ld!",(long)indexPath.row);

}
else if ([tableView isEqual:_categoriesTableView]){

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_categoriesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_categoriesButton setTitle:cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _categoriesTableView.hidden = YES;
    _subCategoriesButton.enabled = YES;
    _subCategoriesButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    NSLog(@"You selected 2------> %ld!",(long)indexPath.row);
    _categorySelectedFlag = YES;


}

else if ([tableView isEqual:_subCategoriesTableView]){

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_subCategoriesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_subCategoriesButton setTitle:cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _subCategoriesTableView.hidden = YES;
    _outcomeButton.enabled = YES;
    _outcomeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    NSLog(@"You selected 3------> %ld!",(long)indexPath.row);

}
}
```

The error is thrown on this line of code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.subcategoryCv objectAtIndex:_selectedSubCategoryIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
```

Comment: Hello ;), can you find and show me which line contains `isEqualToString`?

Comment: Hi @trungduc, the line is this one, 

else if ([tableView isEqual:_subCategoriesTableView]){

        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.subcategoryCv objectAtIndex:_selectedSubCategoryIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
}

Comment: Maybe it's in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Can you show this method?

Comment: i dont not have isEqualToString in my code i only have isEqual

Comment: i added didSelectRowAtIndexPath